# Aligning and Synchronising X Axes in MS Chart Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, charts, axis

I have a chart control (from System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization) with two chart areas.  ChartArea2 is aligned to ChartArea1 as follows:

```
ChartArea2.AlignWithChartArea    = "ChartArea1";
ChartArea2.AlignmentOrientation  = AreaAlignmentOrientations.Vertical;
ChartArea2.AlignmentStyle        = AreaAlignmentStyles.All;
```

This works well except the X Axes are not aligned, despite being included in the AlignmentStyle.  Instead, their minimum, maximum, interval, etc remain independent and are set according to the datapoints.

[image]

I need the X Axes to be identical, i.e. min, max, interval, etc.  I can set these properties in code to force them to be identical. However, as soon as I zoom into ChartArea1, then the X Axes become misaligned again.

Is there a simple way for the X Axes to mirror each other regardless of the zoom level?

Answer (score 0):

Well, they actually are **aligned** , i.e. sit at the same position regardless of their labels but they don't have the same **range**.

You don't see the alignment of the X-Axes when the sit vertically but look at the Y-Axes: They have different Font sizes but sit at the same horizontal position!

If you want to show the same range you need to set the range, as you wrote, by setting the [`Minimum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.minimum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) & [`Maximum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.maximum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the default **`NaN`** (which here means `Automatic`) to some values.

And when you **zoom** one the **other will zoom in parallel** automatically as long as `AreaAlignmentStyles.AxesView` or `AreaAlignmentStyles.All` are selected.

So what you need is the combination of a non-automatic, explicit range (for the unzoomed state) and and a suitable `AreaAlignmentStyle` (for the zoomed state.)

**Note** that the `AlignmentStyle` needs to be made only for **one** of the two `ChartAreas`. But the `Minimum/Maximum` values need to be set for **both**:

```
ChartArea CA1 = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
ChartArea CA2 = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea2");

// 2nd CA aligns to the 1st one:
CA2.AlignWithChartArea = "ChartArea1";
CA2.AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.Vertical;
CA2.AlignmentStyle = AreaAlignmentStyles.All;

// both have the same range:
CA1.AxisX.Maximum = 30;
CA2.AxisX.Maximum = 30;
CA1.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
CA2.AxisX.Minimum = 0;

// both are interactively zoomable:
CA1.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
CA1.AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
CA1.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
CA2.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
CA2.AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
CA2.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
```

[image]

In a zoomed state both `ChartAreas` still show the same range and have the same `ScaleView.ViewMinimum / ScaleView.ViewMaximum`:

[image]

Code to test the `ScaleView` values:

```
private void chart1_AxisViewChanged(object sender, ViewEventArgs e)
{
    AxisScaleView ASV1X = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView;
    AxisScaleView ASV2X = chart1.ChartAreas[1].AxisX.ScaleView;

    label1.Text = "ScaleViews Min/Max: " + ASV1X.ViewMinimum + " - " + ASV1X.ViewMaximum +
                                 " | " +   ASV2X.ViewMinimum + " - " + ASV2X.ViewMaximum ;
    }
```

Note that to keep not only the **value ranges** aligned but also the **visual** display of the Axes you need to use the `AlignmentStyle = AreaAlignmentStyles.All;`, not just `AxisView` or else great differences in the values' formatting results or in the number of points to display can move the Y-Axis and make the X-Axes look misaligned!

Comment: And therein lies the issue.  Even when I set the min and max so they start off aligned, the zoom still does not work as expected.  They zoom in parallel ok.  However, their X Axes (values) are no longer aligned (they have different start points and different scale/interval).  The ScaleView Position and Size are the same on both charts, but their ViewMinimum and ViewMaximum properties are different.  The issue is worst when the first data points of each chart are far from each other.

Comment: I can't reproduce. They zoom in and always have the same range on their x-axes. And therefore they always have the same ViewMinimum/ViewMaximum values. Do check if you have other code at work that messes it up. You need to set Min&Max for __both__ chartareas!

Comment: I've isolated it to two causes: 1) If one series has only 2 to ~4 datapoints compared to the other series having many.  OR 2) If most of the X datapoints are non-integers (i.e. contains fractional number).  I still haven't found a workable solution for it yet.

Comment: I see what you mean, however when I use `AreaAlignmentStyles.All` the effect goes away. I'll update the answer.

Comment: There is a 3rd cause, and its the one giving my project grief: 3) If the X Axis range is very high (several thousand), then the Zoom starts having the problem described.

Answer (score -1):

Setting `ChartArea.AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;` will solve the problem