# Align multiple charts

Tags: c#, data-visualization

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567374/how-can-i-align-the-innerplots) answer, but what happens if you have three `charts`? And in general, have n `charts` stacked one ontop of each other and you want the `chart` bodies (`areas`) to align with each other?

I would be satisfied to see a result for three `charts`, but a `function` that takes a `list` of charts and aligns them is the most useful.

Also, does this answer presume the charts already have **all** data in them? What if the data is added at `runtime` dynamically and you need to keep the charts aligned? The problem is the `y-axis labels` may change in size as new data appears ( a negative sign appears, or more decimal places, more digits, etc), pushing the chart body to the right, and therefore misligning them with other chart areas stacked above/below it.

Being able to assign a stable `Y-axis label extent` no matter how big the label gets goes  along way to solving some of these problems. **How is this done?**

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042419/how-to-draw-four-or-more-workareas-horizontally/27046961#27046961) and maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141291/aligning-and-synchronising-x-axes-in-ms-chart-doesnt-work/37142989#37142989) - Note while you can set the InnerplotPosition the extent of the labels can only be influenced indirectly; best allow for enough space and also format the values to restrict their size.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, assuming `charts` is an array of all the charts -

```
var referenceR = charts
                   .OrderBy(c => c.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF().Width)
                   .FirstOrDefault();

 foreach(var chart in charts)
 {
       chart.Left = referenceR.Left;
       chart.Size = referenceR.Size;
       var r = chart.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF();
       chart.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(referenceR.Left, r.Top, referenceR.Width, r.Height);
 }
```

Comment: All the chart areas  are blank.. Not even the axis display;.

Comment: oops :) Can you try and set debugger and see if referenceR is a chart with minimum width. If yes then `r` has correct `RectangleF` values. I am sorry I do not have any charts data or charts, I just extended the same logic which you shared here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567374/how-can-i-align-the-innerplots)

Comment: Chart only show anything once you have added a DataPoint.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked. I realize it is not what I asked, but for now this seems to be the internal design of the `chart control` "promoted" for solving this sort of problem.

Instead of having three `charts`, I have one `chart` with three `areas`. Then solving the alignment issue is trivial:

```
   chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea2"].AlignWithChartArea = "ChartArea1";
   chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea3"].AlignWithChartArea = "ChartArea1";
```

And everything stays aligned beautifully as data is inserted in realtime.